# Why is the * regex operator not working?

Tags: regex

`[\d-.]+` works but `[\d-.]*` does not.  The only thing I changed is the `+` to `*` at the end.

```
<b>12345</b>
<b>12345-6789</b>
<i>1234.5678</i>
<tag>1234-2342346456</tag>
```

I tested it out here http://regexr.com?30ngn

The `*` means 0 or more while `+` means 1 or more.  Does the `*` only work with `.`?

Comment: what are all these xml lines in the middle?

Comment: show your whole regex and exactly the input string

Comment: No the * works for every regular expression, not only .   , this is a strange issue

Comment: Those are just sample text to search for.  I'm learning regex and I can't figure out why `*` is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*` operator works fine, it's just regexr acting funny, or it is due to your hazardous use of the `-` character in a regex character class. If you want to match a `-` character in a character class, put it at the beginning; otherwise, the regex engine may think you want to match a range (such as `[A-Z]`).

The fixed regex `[-\d.]*` works just fine at [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5B-%5Cd.%5D%2a&input=%3Cb%3E12345%3C/b%3E%0A%3Cb%3E12345-6789%3C/b%3E%0A%3Ci%3E1234.5678%3C/i%3E%0A%3Ctag%3E1234-2342346456%3C/tag%3E%0A).

Comment: Hmm I see, it is just a problem with the site.

Comment: Seems to be the site.  Not even `[\d]*` works while `[\d]+ does.